# AirlineFlightSchedules method in the new API

Tags: travel-time

Somebody know how is the AirlineFlightSchedules method in the new Flight Aware API: AeroAPI 4.16.0?

I can not find the way to do it with the new API with the old API was just using AirlineFlightSchedules endpoint but it does not exist anymore

I need to get info for future flights by flight code and date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GET /schedules/{date_start}/{date_end} endpoint will return scheduled flights that have been published by airlines.
These schedules are available for up to 12 months in the future and 3 months in the past.
You can find it in the documentation down at the very bottom, in the Miscellaneous section.
But this new endpoint does not have the info as before with the timezones, name of airports and distances. So if you need the name of the airport instead of the airport code you need to request it on the airport API, if you need the route distance as well will be another endpoint